# NodeJS HTTPOnly cookie not being sent with fetch function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies

I'm having problems with cookie authentication between an expressJS server and a VueJS font-end.

When logging in through the site, I successfully get a HTTPOnly Cookie in the set-cookie header:
[Screenshot (Ignore the Auth header, using it for testing only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQS5x.png)

I also see the [cookie in the devTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPjow.png), and everything looks right too me, I'm not an expert on cookies though so it may not be correct

The problem is when I request the user's settings on another endpoint, the cookie is not sent to the server. The `req.cookie` object is empty when the this request is handled on the server side.

Here is my fetch code:

```
const loginOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-cache',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  }),
  credentials: 'same-origin',
};

const settingsOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-cache',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  credentials: 'same-origin',
};

const loginResponse = await fetch(baseUrl + '/login', loginOptions);
const userSettings = await fetch(baseUrl + '/settings', settingsOptions);
```

I've tried using `credentials: "include"`, without success.

On the express server I'm using cors like this:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
}));
```

[Here is also an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkJbE.png) of the second request, the `403` status is set by the server when no cookie is attached to the request.

I've tried setting the domain of the cookie to both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as suggested in another thread. [I have left it on `localhost` for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Vjy.png).

#### Solved

I had read somewhere that you should add a specific domain value to the cookie when creating it. If I just removed that setting, it sets it automatically I'm guessing, and then it worked! So my guess is that I had set the domain value to the wrong value for what I was trying to do

Comment: What is the relationship between the value of `baseUrl` and the URL from which the page calling `fetch()` was loaded? If the cookies are being set for `localhost:3000`, then the browser will only send them to `localhost:3000` and not any other port.

Comment: I take it you've checked the second request in the dev tools to see if the cookie is being sent in the request header

Comment: oh, and try firefox instead too, just to rule out the *chrome feature* pointed out in one of the answers

Comment: baseUrl has the value `localhost:3000`, I'm sending the requests from `localhost:8080`. Is this the problem?

Comment: About the Chrome _feature_, I've also tried firefox and it's the same there unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your response has `access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080` which implies you are making a cross-origin request.

You said:

> ```
> credentials: 'same-origin',
> ```

… which tells your client-side code to only include credentials for same-origin requests.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think that that will send cookies to a different method/host/port combination.

Comment: @JaromandaX if you look at the headers linked in the OP, the page looks like it was loaded from `localhost:3000` not `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that Chrome wasn't friendly with cookies and localhost env, maybe it could be that.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

Furthermore, I had some problems with cookies, express and vueJS some times ago.

Maybe it can help you: [SetCookie header not stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713238/setcookie-header-not-stored)

Answer (score 0):

I had read somewhere that you should add a specific domain value to the cookie when creating it. If I just removed that setting, it sets it automatically I'm guessing, and then it worked! So my guess is that I had set the domain value to the wrong value for what I was trying to do